# Is a draw from the posterior always the same as a draw from the prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, marginal-distribution

I'm reading [Bayesian data analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/). On page 155, the authors state:

> Each of the [...] parameters were assigned independent Beta(2, 2) prior distributions. ... If the model were true, we would expect any single simulation draw of the vector of [parameters] to look like independent draws from the Beta(2, 2) distribution.

I assume "simulation draw" here means a draw from the posterior distribution. To me this seems to imply that a draw from the posterior is the same as a draw from the prior, which already seems strange to me. In the derivation as to why this is true, the authors use only very general arguments that do not rely on any specifics of the example or the Beta(2, 2) distribution. Since this reasoning is so general it would apply to any Bayesian analysis. So, to me, it looks like the authors are stating here: "the posterior distribution is always the same as the prior". Which cannot be true!

But where did I miss something? Is a simulation draw not a draw from the posterior? (The wording of this book is always extremely vague or imprecise.) What else am I missing?

Or is it the book that is wrong? (Unlikely.)

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Drawing from the posterior is generally different from drawing from the prior. They're only the same if the prior and posterior are equal (meaning we learn nothing from the data about the quantities of interest). The authors probably mean something else.

Comment: These comments apply to the prior. It means that in an ideal Bayesian model, the value of the parameter $\theta$ corresponding to the sampling model (of the data) could have been generated from a Beta $\mathcal Be(2,2)$ distribution. Obviously, this does not mean anything with _one_ single realisation, but in the imaginary repetition of such an Bayesian experiment, the collection of the parameters along repetitions could suit an iid sequence from the Beta $\mathcal Be(2,2)$ distribution.